# can't seem to get right php regex quantifier

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string that looks like this:

```
msg": "log domain jl.lab.test.net server lab-jl-ppr-web"
```

I'm trying to extract "jl.lab.test.net" and JUST "lab-jl-ppr" from "lab-jl-ppr-web" using the following regular expression:

```
 preg_match("/\"msg\"\: \"log domain\s([\w*\.]*) server ([\w*\.\-]*)/i",$line,$matches);
```

The second group currently matches the entire "lab-jl-ppr-web" string.  I have been trying to specify the proper quantifier but so far I haven't gotten the right one.  I've tried the following:

```
 preg_match("/\"msg\"\: \"log domain\s([\w*\.]*) server ([\w*\.\-]*){3}/i",$line,$matches);
```

I'm continuing to play with it but if you have any tips, i'd appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: please update your question to include a few examples, and your expected final output, the wording that you currently use makes it confusing.

Comment: `[]` matches a single character, `[]{3}` would match 3 of the specified characters in a row. it will NOT match 3 SETS of 3 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just

```
/..snip.. server ([\w*\.\-]*)-web/i
```

? Just keep `-web` outside of the capture group.

Answer (score 1):

This probably works

```
'~"msg":[ ]"log[ ]domain\s([\w.]*)[ ]server[ ]((?:(?!-web)[\w.-])*)~'
```

but, it's hard to get what you're looking for from the regex.

Expanded

```
 "msg": [ ] "log [ ] domain \s 
 ( [\w.]* )                    # (1)
 [ ] server [ ] 
 (                             # (2 start)
      (?:
           (?! -web )
           [\w.-] 
      )*
 )                             # (2 end)
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 52 ) 
"msg": "log domain jl.lab.test.net server lab-jl-ppr  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 19 , len 15 ) 
jl.lab.test.net  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 42 , len 10 ) 
lab-jl-ppr
```

Answer (score 0):

That one seems legit but i'm sure better one can be written.

```
^log domain ([a-zA-Z\.]+) server ([a-zA-Z\.\-]+)-web$
```

Here you can test it

[LiveRegex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach with `preg_match_all` function:

```
$str = "log domain jl.lab.test.net server lab-jl-ppr-web";
preg_match_all("/\b\w+\.\w+\.\w+\.\w+\b|\b\w+-\w+-\w+(?=-\w+?)\b/U", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => jl.lab.test.net
    [1] => lab-jl-ppr
)
```